# Why isn't iTunes working for me?

Tags: wine, apple, itunes

I know you are to install iTunes in WINE but when ever I open it an error message appears that says

```
Apple Application Support was not found.
Apple Application Support is required to run iTunes. Please uninstall
iTunes, then install iTunes again.

Error 2(Windows error 2)
```

I have tried uninstalling the iTunes, re downloading it and repairing it.  Nothing seems to work.  Please help me here.  Thank you.

Comment: I am aware of gtkiPod and stuff like that, but I want to use iTunes for the setup of my iPod.

Comment: if all you want to do is sync content to your iPod then gtkiPod or Banshee will achieve this for you, iTunes is a buggy program at best on Windows and the only real difference between the others and it is that it will enable you to update the software of the iPod. Apple never update the software for older iPods when a new model is released - the only difference being the touch screen versions (nano & touch).

Comment: Ja I know but for my iPod shuffle in order to set the voice over to on and stuff like that I have to use iTunes.  I already have banshee and I haven't tried it, but I haven't tested yet to see whether or no it will let me change the settings in banshee, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also tried this, it didn't work for me. 
iTunes was rated as Silver on the Winehq website, with few known reports of it working properly. http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347 
I use banshee, it's simple, lightweight, and all around in my opinion, it's better than iTunes. It also allows you to Sync media to your iPod or iPhone, but with limited functionality. 
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

iTunes will not be fully usable with WINE, no matter how you try. Have you tried synchronising your iPod with Banshee, you may have far better luck that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing iTunes with [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/).  It's a small program that automates the process of using wine to install Windows Applications.  Plus, it also searches "dependencies"(kind of, in your case, Apple Application Support) for Windows applications and installs it automatically.

If PlayOnLinux doesn't work, then you can try installing the [Apple Application Support](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc6qo8yq9no3sh5/AppleApplicationSupport.msi) Standalone Package using wine and then install iTunes.  I extracted the file from the iTunes Installer.

Answer (score -3):

Some versions work with some versions of wine. If you'd chosen a product from a more open company then you would have significantly fewer issues. I suggest you check the wine appdb for your version of wine running the version of iTunes you have. You may need the wine ppa adding ad run wine 1.3

Alternatively you could drop the ipod and get a decent device.

Comment: Checking the [Wine appdb](http://appdb.winehq.org/) for iTunes version supported looks perfectly o.k. with me.

Comment: Ja but still iPods are reliably good and are known throughout their life not to be complete crap.  Trust me I have gotten some good and some crap mp3 players.

Comment: Ok I'll update my WINE